# Problem importing numpy in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

Just yesterday it was working, and it still imports in spyder, but for some reason I cannot import into jupyter notebook.

```
import numpy as np
```

gets error message

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\dturo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "", line 1, in 
import numpy

File "C:\Users\dturo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py", line 106
"""

^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Edit_________________________
Issue resolved, somehow the actual *init*.py file for numpy got changed, so I had to just fix that. Unsure how it happened, I had left my pc running so maybe my cat did some trolling

Comment: which system are you on? what was your source for anaconda? is this the complete trace of the error?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I'm on windows 10, and that is the full traceback

Answer (score 0):

Try writing this in the jupyter notebook:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy
```

Then:

```
import numpy as np
```

Comment: Ya this was my instinct as well, but weirdly it just says requirement already satisfied, then I get the same error